# Convert CSV file into 2D array using StringTokenizer

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm trying to convert a CSV file into a 2D array however I'm having problems. The code seems to only print out first name in the CSV file 10 times and then gives me an out of bounds exception. E.g if Player name was Rob, it will just print out Rob over and over again.

If any more clarification needed just ask

```
try{
    int col = 0, row = 0;
    System.out.println("Reading " + fileName + " ...");
    fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = bf.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            data[row][col] = st.nextToken();
            col++;
        }
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }
}catch(IOException e){
    System.err.println("Cannot find: "+fileName);
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation for `StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code_. Don't use it. Further, use a real CSV parser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code reads just one line. Continue the while loop using the following code snippet -

```
String line = bf.readLine();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //place your code here 
}
```

In the above code `BufferedReader` - `br` is now ready to read the next line and it continues until the `br.readline()` returns a null.

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.